# Class template, no constructor could take the source(string)

Tags: c++, string, templates, constructor

attempting to compile the code gives several errors(error codes at the bottom)

```
//heap.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class TYPE>
class Heap{
private:

    vector<TYPE> heap;
    int size;// number of elements in the heap
    bool maxheap = true;
    TYPE bubble_up(TYPE item);
    TYPE bubble_down(TYPE item);

public:

    Heap();
    Heap(bool maxheap);
    Heap(vector<TYPE>, bool order);
    ~Heap();
    void build_heap();
    TYPE Insert(TYPE item);
    TYPE Delete(TYPE& item);
    const vector<TYPE> sort(bool order);
    const vector<TYPE> sort();// defualt sort if no variable given, max sort
    TYPE get_size();
    void print_heap();
    void clear_heap();
};

template<class TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::Heap(){
    TYPE dummy{};
    heap.push_back(dummy);
    size = heap.size() - 1;
}

template<class TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::Heap(bool order){
    maxheap = order; // true is max, false is min
    TYPE dummy{};
    heap.push_back(dummy);
    size = heap.size() - 1;

}

template<class TYPE>
Heap<TYPE>::Heap(vector<TYPE> x, bool order){
    maxheap = order;// true is max, false is min
    TYPE tempSize;
    TYPE dummy{};
    heap.push_back(dummy);
    size = heap.size() - 1;
    tempSize = x.size();
    for (TYPE y = 0; y < tempSize; y++){
        heap.push_back(x[y]);
    }
    size = heap.size() - 1;
    build_heap();
}

template<class TYPE>
TYPE Heap<TYPE>::Insert(TYPE item){
    heap.push_back(item);
    size = heap.size() - 1;
    return bubble_up(size);
}

TYPE Heap<TYPE>::bubble_up(TYPE pos){

    TYPE retVal;
    if (pos == 1)// root of tree
    {
        return pos;
    }
    if (maxheap == true){

        if (heap[pos] > heap[pos / 2]){// greater than parent
            TYPE temp = heap[pos / 2]; //swap method
            heap[pos / 2] = heap[pos];
            heap[pos] = temp;
            return retVal = bubble_up(pos / 2);
        }
        else{
            return pos;
        }
    }
    if (maxheap == false){//min heap
        if (heap[pos] < heap[pos / 2]){// less than parent
            TYPE temp = heap[pos / 2]; //swap method
            heap[pos / 2] = heap[pos];
            heap[pos] = temp;
            return retVal = bubble_up(pos / 2);
        }
        else{
            return pos;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the driver file currently being used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Heap.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
typedef string TYPE;

int main(void) {

    Heap<std::string> *s_heap = new Heap<std::string>();  // string heap
    std::string s_item = "0";
    vector<std::string> s_blah(11, s_item);

    cout << "\n*** Test insert elements ***";
    cout << endl << s_heap->Insert("15");
    cout << endl << s_heap->Insert("1");
    cout << endl << s_heap->Insert("3");
    cout << endl << s_heap->Insert("4");

    cout << endl;
}
```

full error code:

```
c:\users\\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\pa 3 templates\pa 3 templates\heap.h(85): error 

C2664: 'std::string Heap<std::string>::bubble_up(TYPE)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'std::string'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TYPE=std::string
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
1>          c:\users\\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\pa 3 templates\pa 3 templates\heap.h(82) : while compiling class template member function 'std::string Heap<std::string>::Insert(TYPE)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TYPE=std::string
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\pa 3 templates\pa 3 templates\driver.cpp(17) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::string Heap<std::string>::Insert(TYPE)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              TYPE=std::string
1>          ]
```

Comment: `Heap<std::string> *s_heap = new Heap<std::string>();`  No need  to dynamically allocate.  C++ isn't Java  `Heap<std::string> s_heap;`
is all you need.

Comment: `bubble_up()` is declared as taking a `TYPE` param, but the calls to it, and the usage inside, makes it clear it should take an `int` instead.

Comment: `bubble_up()` takes a `TYPE` object (which is `std::string` in your instantiation) but you're providing an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a handful of problems here, mostly related to your attempt to make your `Heap` generic, which you've failed to do.

You're trying to create a heap of `std::string` (despite all the values you're adding being numbers, but lets skip that form the moment).

The argument of `bubble_up` will therefor also be a string:

```
TYPE Heap<TYPE>::bubble_up(TYPE pos){
```

The problem comes in lines like this:

```
if (pos == 1)// root of tree
```

and this:

```
heap[pos / 2] = heap[pos];
```

You're trying to compare a string with a number in the first case, and trying to perform division on the string in the second case! This isn't going to work. The problem can only get worse if you try to pass in structs and classes and whatever else.

You will either need to enforce that TYPE is an integral type that you can perform these operations on, or seriously rewrite the way your heap works.

To allow a generic-ish heap that fails with a sensible error when supplied a non-integral `TYPE`, you can do this:

```
template<class TYPE>
class Heap{
private:
static_assert(std::is_integral<TYPE>::value, "Must be an integral type");
```

If you actually wanted your heap to work with strings... well. That's another problem altogether. You could try storing a hash of all your values:

```
#include <functional>
// ...
std::hash<TYPE> hashfunc;
size_t hashval = hashfunc(pos);
```

Hash functions are defined for all the standard library types, and return a nice integral `size_t` value that can be fed to the rest of your heap algorithm without any substantial changes, I think. You'd still need to keep a mapping back from hash values to original data if you wanted to return useful values from `bubble_up`, etc, but I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.